# Accessing Redux selector value in a custom hook

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-hooks

I'm writing my first hook and I also use redux.
I'm listening to orientation sensor data from the mobile device in React native and when it updates I filter it to see if the new value is different than the old value before I send it over to redux state to be stored.

I'm noticing in the filterData method the data is always null. But if I console log the storedVal in the render I see it's always being updated and it's updated in the Redux store as well.

But for some reason filterData only has access to the initial value and doesn't get the updated values. Any idea how to fix this?

```
  const storedVal = useSelector(selectors.selectStoredVal);

  const filterData = useCallback(
    () => {
      console.log(storedVal);
    },
    [storedVal]
  );

  useEffect(
     () => {
        orientation.pipe(filter(filterData)).subscribe((data) => {
             console.log('Data filtered correctly, new data received here');
        }
     }
  ), 
  [];
}
```

Comment: What does the `filter()` function do? Is it calling filterData (which is itself a function)? Your callback function doesn't return anything, should it? Does your code work if you don't use `useCallback`? Remember, that's an optimization technique, it shouldn't actually change the functionality of your code.

Comment: Your useEffect is inside filterData...

Comment: Try add `filterData` function as dependency for `useEffect` like `useEffect(() => {...}, [filterData])`

Answer (score 0):

An empty dependency array for `useEffect` means that the callback function within it will only run once (on component mount).

`useCallback` is creating a function that is being passed into the filter function. Because `storedVal` is a dependency for `filteredData`, went `storedVal` changes and `filteredData` is updated to a new function, your `useEffect` still has a reference to it's old value.

Try adding `[filteredData]` to your dependency array for the `useEffect`.

Comment: I'm subscribing to the orientation sensor in my useEffect which I don't want to redo after the initial component mounting.

Comment: Is unsubscribing then resubscribing a possibility? Or if there is a method for orientation that allows you to update the filter function? Not too familiar with react-native sorry.